# Okta Service with angular

Tags: angular5, okta

I am using Okta signin widget, I got user info. But I am unable to getting the specific user groups data(user belonging to which group) with okta login with angular.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want to configure custom claims:

https://developer.okta.com/standards/OAuth/#custom-scopes-and-claims

Let me know if that documentation is helpful?